# Did China engage in spy swaps?

Tags: united-states, international-relations, china, espionage

The Soviet union and then Russia regularly engaged in [spy swaps](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2010/jul/08/spy-swaps-history-russia) with the West (even if [a recent trend](https://www.businessinsider.com/sergei-skripal-poisoning-russia-spy-swap-deals-at-risk-2018-3) seems to be to "get them good" even after the swap, at least on select occasions.) But historically they did these spy swaps.

Did China do the same? The fairly recent [execution en block](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/us-politics/us-spy-network-china-exposed-cia-officer-arrested-a8164586.html) of "CIA assets" in their country seems to suggest China doesn't do spy swaps. Is that the case, historically?

Answer (score 1):

There was spy swap between Taiwan and China 2015 as described [here](https://spyscape.com/article/the-big-spy-swap-10-key-prisoner-exchanges-in-history):

> Taiwan and China swap (2015) ‍
>
> News of the first spy exchange between China and Taiwan emerged in
> 2015 when the Taipei press revealed the release of Li Zhihao, a
> mysterious Chinese intelligence officer known as ‘the man in black’
> who’d been serving a life sentence in Taiwan. In return, Beijing
> reportedly freed Chu Kung-hsun and Hsu Chang-kuo, two Colonels in
> Taiwan’s Military Information Bureau, who were arrested a decade
> earlier. The BBC described the swap as a mutual gesture of goodwill
> ahead of talks between leaders of both countries.

[This article](https://www.scmp.com/news/china/policies-politics/article/1885365/taiwan-and-mainland-chinas-spy-swap-sign-how-far-cross) also contain some information about that spy swap between Taiwan and China.